How to update object with Linq-To-SQL but with System.Data.Linq.DataContext
I have the following straightforward case where a client communicates with .NET Web API:

Client makes a request for an object to the Web API giving the requested ID.
Web API returns the object to the client.
Client changes several properties of the object.
Client sends back the object (not the changed properties) to the Web API using PUT method.
Web API has to use linq-to-sql to update the database.

I am not able to get step 5 implemented.
Here is the code I am using:
[HttpPut]
[ActionName("Update")]
public IHttpActionResult Update(MyModel myModel)
{
    this.context.MyModel.Attach(myModel);
    this.context.SubmitChanges();
    
    return Ok();
}

This code does not work.
We also know that the endpoints of WebAPI are stateless.
I have seen other solutions like this:
[HttpPut]
[ActionName("Update")]
public IHttpActionResult Update(MyModel myModel)
{
    this.context.MyModel.Add(myModel);
    this.context.Entry(myModel).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    this.context.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}

But the problem with this code is that I am using System.Data.Linq.DataContext which does not have the property Entry.
Is there a way to do that using System.Data.Linq.DataContext?
UPDATE:
I have tried the following as @Alexander proposed:
this.context.MyModel.Attach(myModel, true);
context.SubmitChanges();

This returns the following error: An entity can only be attached as modified without original state if it declares a version member or does not have an update check policy. which might be due to the fact that the context has now changed.
Then I tried out the following:
var currentDbModel = this.context.MyModel.GetByKey(myModel.ID);
this.context.MyModel.Attach(myModel, currentDbModel);
context.SubmitChanges();

But this raises the following error:
"Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use."

What works is the following code now:
var currentDbModel = this.context.MyModel.GetByKey(myModel.ID);
this.context = new DataContext(this.cnn);
this.context.MyModel.Attach(myModel, currentDbModel);
context.SubmitChanges();

The problem with the code above is that first I have to get the current record from the database again and also renew the datacontext afterwards. I wonder if this can be optimized somehow?

System.Data.Linq.DataContext is ooooollddd - do you have a good reason why you can't remove it from your project entirely and use a new scaffolded System.Data.Entity.DbContext instead?

Also, you should not be using Entity classes as DTOs - that's how you get hacked (because it means any remote-client can set arbitrary data in your properties). You need to design purpose-built DTOs instead.

Yes, it is a very old but huge project and we have the restriction not change this part of it. So we have to use the old System.Data.Linq.DataContext.

It is not Entity Framework. It is LINQ to SQL - the predecessor of EF.

I think, you should use other overload of Attach method. Attach(myModel, true)

@AlexanderPetrov I have updated the question and explained the results.

There are three ways to update entities in EF Core: Updating an entity. In fact, the same applies in LINQ to SQL.
